# vertx get body of a simple post reques

Tags: java, vert.x

Their [doc on vertx website isn't quite clear on how to receive the body of a request](http://vertx.io/docs/vertx-web/java/#_request_body_handling).

```
var vertx = Vertx.vertx();
var server = vertx.createHttpServer();
var Router = require("vertx-web-js/router");
var BodyHandler = require("vertx-web-js/body_handler");


var router = Router.router(vertx);


router.route().handler(BodyHandler.create().handle);

router.route('POST', "/a").handler(function (routingContext) {
  var response = routingContext.response();
  response.setChunked(true);
  response.write("a json received");
  var str = routingContext.getBodyAsJson()
  console.log(str);
  // Now end the response
  routingContext.response().end();
});
```

I get the error:

```
 vertx-js/util/console.js:9 ReferenceError: "inspect" is not defined
```

How am I supposed to know what to call if they don't even put it in their doc..

Comment: What version of vert.x are you using? that seems like a bug with the console object implementation that has been fixed on 3.3.3 - https://github.com/vert-x3/vertx-lang-js/commit/2af2b50eb7493898e28e3ecc929ee21face71fc4 . Regarding the code above it does seem to be correct though.

Comment: @PauloLopes I'm indeed using a lower version I'm using the one in the blog post http://vertx.io/blog/vert-x3-says-hello-to-npm-users/

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Paulo said my version of vertx was outdated and this was a bug. I'll take his word for it. In the meantime I tried doing it in Java like in the answer I got. However I had more success doing it like this:

```
   router.route().handler(BodyHandler.create());


   router.route(HttpMethod.POST, "/iamonline").handler(rc -> {
        JsonObject json = rc.getBodyAsJson();
        System.out.println(json.getString("id"));
        HttpServerResponse response = rc.response();
        response.putHeader("content-type", "application/json");

        // Write to the response and end it
        response.end("{\"status\": 200}");
    });
```

Answer (score 5):

I ran into the same the first time. Use the `.bodyHandler` which is a convenience method for receiving the entire request body in one piece.

As a reference, I'll give you an example in Java (you can easily "transform" it into ECMAScript):

```
public void login(final RoutingContext routingContext) {
  routingContext.request().bodyHandler(bodyHandler -> {
    final JsonObject body = bodyHandler.toJsonObject();
    // `body` now contains you what you POST'ed
  });
}
```

Comment: I get an exception `Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Request has already been read` with this approach.